Map over a list of lists of arbitrary depth in Haskell
One can map over a list of lists of arbitrary depth as follows:
map           :: (a -> b) ->   [a]   ->   [b]
(map.map)     :: (a -> b) ->  [[a]]  ->  [[b]]
(map.map.map) :: (a -> b) -> [[[a]]] -> [[[b]]]

Is it possible to write a single function handling all such cases? Uiua has the ∵ each function which does this on an array of arbitrary rank. Such functions are called pervasive functions in array languages.

You would have to write your own function handling the recursion. Haskell functions are not automatically rank-polymorphic. This is typically only seen with Array languages such as APL, BQN, or Uiua.

It's possible to write this specific operator, but in general this type of thing is not easy to do and a bit un-haskelly. If you had multiple operators working like this in conjunction you'd almost certainly run into type inference issues as well.

Oh that's a good point, hadn't thought about type inference issues! Hmmm

Even just this one operator has murky semantics when considering type synonyms. Suppose I define type TemperatureLog = [Temperature]. When I write ubermap f (logs :: [TemperatureLog]), what should be the type of f? Should it be TemperatureLog -> TemperatureLog, or Temperature -> Temperature?

I'd mention a 2006 thread from the Haskell mailing lists on this topic. Sometimes this is called the "deepest functor" problem, IIRC. There is no completely satisfactory solution, AFAIK, even with modern Haskell. What you might be able to obtain today is something like ubermap @4 my_nested_list where you specify the nesting level as a type-level argument @4. I'm not that familiar with KnownNat but it could be doable.

Well I mean, if the language allows this sort of thing, it seems we'd like to be able to choose so that it operates at either maximum or minimum possible depth. Probably maximal.

This paper seems relevant: https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/aplicative.pdf

Nested lists are probably too general to guide type inference effectively, so even though it's pretty simple to implement deepmap as a type class:
class DeepMap a b a' b' where
  deepmap :: (a -> b) -> [a'] -> [b']

instance DeepMap a b a b where
  deepmap = map
instance (DeepMap a b a' b') => DeepMap a b [a'] [b'] where
  deepmap = map . deepmap

you have to provide a lot of guidance to the type checker to use it:
main = do
  print $ deepmap @Int @Int @Int @Int (*2) $ [1,2]
  print $ deepmap @Int @Int @[Int] @[Int] (*2) $ [[1],[2]]

If all four type parameters for the DeepMap class are resolved by context, then it works okay:
main = do
    print $ (deepmap ord ["ab","c"] :: [[Int]])

In real code, you'd probably introduce a new data type to represent such arrays, like this GADT with type-level indexing of the array rank.  (Indexing by a type of kind [Int] representing the dimensions would probably make even more sense, if you were really trying to represent terms in an "array language".)
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Array n a where
  Scalar :: a -> Array Z a
  Array :: [Array n a] -> Array (S n) a
deriving instance (Show a) => Show (Array Z a)
deriving instance (Show (Array n a)) => Show (Array (S n) a)

This type allows a pretty straightforward deepmap implementation:
deepmap :: (a -> b) -> Array n a -> Array n b
deepmap f (Scalar x) = Scalar (f x)
deepmap f (Array xs) = Array (fmap (deepmap f) xs)

main = do
  print $ deepmap (*2) $ Scalar 1
  print $ deepmap (*2) $ Array [Scalar 1, Scalar 2]
  print $ deepmap (*2) $ Array [Array [Scalar 1], Array [Scalar 2]]


There are four FDs you could attach -- any three of the variables determine the other one -- that might help with some of the need for type annotation (e.g. it would eliminate the need for annotation in your deepmap ord example). Also, if you're going the type hackery route, you might consider polymorphic recursion; data Array a = Scalar a | Array (Array [a]). Your nested examples need many fewer constructors then, e.g. Array (Array (Scalar [[1], [2]])) for your final line. Though in this world the constructor names might need some tweaking; Scalar isn't really right any more.

Is it fair to say the common sense answer to this question is: "don't do this"? I suppose the reason why it's relatively easier to implement in array languages is because the typechecker has no need to know the type of anything?

Also I suppose it's impossible to get it to generalize to scalars? I think the APL-family functions will handle rank 0 stuff as well.

If your goal is to do things more concisely than map.map.map, then certainly defining Array is far too complex to be worth the cost, unfortunately. I can't see myself using this in "real code".

@lanf Yes, it is easy to generalize DeepMap to work cleanly on scalars; simply delete the square brackets in the type declaration for deepmap and replace the base-case instance with deepmap = id. Yes, I think the common sense answer is "don't do this".

Closed type families are handy for this type of things (no type annotation is needed if the list is not polymorphic):
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

-- | Helper type function to distinguish list (e.g. `[a]`) from non-list
type family IsList a where
  IsList [a] = True
  IsList a = False

-- | Helper type class which includes auxiliary lifted `Bool` flag
--   (the result of `IsList fa` application)
class GRFunctor (i :: Bool) a b fa fb where
    grmap :: Proxy i -> (a -> b) -> fa -> fb

-- | `IsList [fa] == True` case which recursively uses `GRFunctor` for `fa`
instance (GRFunctor (IsList fa) a b fa fb, fb' ~ [fb]) => GRFunctor True a b [fa] fb' where
    grmap _ = map . grmap (Proxy :: Proxy (IsList fa))

-- | Base recurion case when we unwrapped the list to its underlying non-list ype `fa ~ a`
instance (fa ~ a, fb ~ b) => GRFunctor False a b fa fb where
    grmap _ = id


-- | Recursive functor type class (the actual implementation of `rmap`)
class RFunctor a b fa fb where
    rmap :: (a -> b) -> fa -> fb

-- | Implementation which uses `GRFunctor` to map over arbitrary nested list
instance (GRFunctor (IsList fa) a b fa fb) => RFunctor a b fa fb where
    rmap = grmap (Proxy :: Proxy (IsList fa))

-- | A few examples (no type annotation is needed)
t0 = rmap succ [1..5::Int]

t1 = rmap succ [[[1..5::Int]]]

t2 = rmap not [[[[True, False]]]]

-- | Also works for nested sublists
t3 = rmap not [[[[[True, False]], [[False]]]]]

